# Are unauthorized ballot boxes a new and solely American method of election fraud?

Tags: election, election-fraud

Recently there was a case of Republican Party of the US [illegally placing unauthorized ballot drop-boxes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/ca-gop-ballot-drop-boxes/), to harvest legitimate ballots and presumably perform some illegal activity with them. This was first time I've heard of this type of election fraud, so I wonder, does this type of thing happen in other countries? Also, did it happen in the US before, or is it a novel type of fraud?

Comment: Voting fraud, of any sort, isn't widespread in the US. Period.

Comment: Other than the collection boxes being illegal how is it voting fraud? Unauthorized ballot collection boxes don't cause any fraud with the ballots unless you are claiming that the ballots that get turned into them don't get turned in to be counted.

Comment: I am in no way condoning the activities of the CA Republican Party in this case. So far as I can tell, they are violating the law. Nevertheless, they claim that they will turn the ballots in for counting in the usual fashion, and I've not seen any hard evidence to the contrary. Based on the evidence we've seen so far, I'm reluctant to characterize this as anywhere near as bad as the NC-9 election in 2018.

Comment: I think the method of fraud is technically not possible in most other countries because postal voting doesn't use any special ballot drop boxes. If you do postal voting in for example Germany, your vote is sent by regular mail. So this type of fraud doesn't exist.

Comment: @quarague You can also drop off your mail-in ballot in Germany; either directly into the local town hall’s letterbox or by visiting their office and handing it over. I did both. Likewise, I believe it is possible (and usually expected) to mail US ballots using USPS – although I have heard reports that warn of potentially long delivery times resulting in mailed ballots potentially missing the deadlines which encourages using drop-off locations.

Comment: Is it fraud though?

Comment: IMO “election or voter fraud” are terms that are misapplied. The activity described is better referred to as potential election interference. Various state jurisdictions have legislated to prevent interference.

Comment: @BobE Agreed, though fraud could still be possible, if for example they try to remove ballots voting for certain candidates, or toss in forged/manipulated ballots in with the valid ones, etc.  That's what people who are spooked by this are scared by: it's all being handled by a group with a very clear partisan motive, which has in particular actively sought to establish frequently debunked voter fraud issues, and with moral ambiguity enough to potentially create it themselves, with no oversight.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy  yep --- Interesting sidebar, only 88 dropboxes in Ohio, all at front door of local BOEs, but unmanned (video surveillance ??) Kicker is that by State law only certain relatives of the voter can drop ballots  (but no one is there to check). Odd that a grandparent can drop off, but a grandchild cannot--- go figure

Comment: Do we have a similar Question about voter suppression - citizens in minority neighborhoods waiting hours to vote while it takes minutes in white neighborhoods?

Comment: Are ballot boxes that are not a regular mailbox, the box at an actual inperson voting location, or at the actual board of elections new for 2020 in most US locations?

Comment: Note that the ballot boxes in question are often being placed near what would probably be assumed to be _Republican friendly_ locations (gun shops, etc), and the information of the location disseminated from Republicans themselves.  That is, they aren't likely to receive many ballots not voting for Republican candidates.  The boxes, then, are unlikely to be an attempt to limit votes for Democrat candidates, but rather to set and control a narrative.  For example, consider what happens if the CA officials reject all ballots harvested this way.

Answer (score 4):

Something like that has happened in [Germany](https://taz.de/Urteil-zu-Wahlbetrug-im-Altenheim-vertagt/!352286/) (link in German), on a small scale. Elderly residents in a retirement home got induced by the staff to vote a certain way.

In another case in [Germany](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/urteil-gegen-linke-nach-wahlfaelschung-15634416.html) (link in German), immigrants who could not speak the language were asked to request absentee ballots. (For municipal elections, any EU citizen can vote.)

In both cases more happened than mere harvesting but the harvesting contributed. There is always a little suspicion in settings like this -- elderly, possibly not *quite* lucid voters, staff who help them with administrative chores, nobody else to watch.

**Violating the prescribed handling of ballot materials could be characterized as *voting fraud*, at least in colloquial language. The rules *might* legitimately ban ballot harvesting, or they *might* not.**

When a voter comes to a regular polling station on election day, the identity of the voter gets checked against available documents, the voter is handed a ballot (or the electronic equivalent), the voter goes to an empty booth and marks the ballot, and the ballot goes into the ballot box. All but the marking happens in view of the local election officials and possibly a random group of other voters who are waiting in line.

- If I claim to be my grandmother, the officials should wonder.
- If my daddy wants to double-check my ballot, the officials should stop him. (That one has become harder to enforce with widespread smartphones. He could make me take a picture.)
- If I am actually deceased, the officials should smell a rat.
- If I do not immediately put my ballot into the ballot box, the officials should remind me.
- If I put my ballot into the ballot box, I can be confident that it will be counted.

A mailed ballot replaces these safeguards by different safeguards. In most cases there is an outer envelope with a signed affidavit and an inner envelope with the ballot paper. Some jurisdictions require a witness to countersign. Some jurisdictions require an absentee ballot to be requested, which gives one more opportunity to compare signatures, and the official ballot would be delivered by the postal service to supposed recipient.

- If a thousand voters request their absentee ballots to the same little hutch in the wood, the postman should wonder and report.
- If a random stranger walks down a street and steals ballot forms from the letter box, some resident should wonder and call the police.
- If one person delivers a sack full of ballot letters to the post office, the postman should wonder.
- If I put my ballot into the mail, I can be confident that it will arrive. I'm handing it to the official postal service, not to some random stanger.

Some argue that the safeguards for mail voting are fatally weaker than those for in-person voting. They may be weaker, but they have been good enough for military personnel for ages. But [ballot harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballot_collection) weakens some of those safeguards even more.
So it would be legitimate to completment the rules on absentee ballots by a prohibition of ballot harvesting.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a local politician in a Western democracy (not the US), there was a situation where one of our observers at a polling count noticed a streak of postal ballots being verified where all of the addresses on the ballot papers were from the same retirement home, which housed large numbers of elderly people who had dementia and similar.  All of the addresses had been filled out, very strangely, using pink ink, suggesting they had all been completed at the same time.

On election night, there was a consistent streak of votes for the opposing party, all of which were written using pink ink.

We subsequently found out that a local and somewhat notorious politician from the opposing party had visited said elderly care home and "spoken to" the residents.

Worth pointing out that, at that time, my party attracted an overwhelming share of the elderly vote nationally and it was the opposing party which typically had the youth vote.

A bit dubious, to say the least.

Comment: Interesting, but this answer doesn't mention any unauthorized ballot boxes.